# Google Cloud Data Fusion ingest Excel to Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-data-fusion

I am trying to create a simple pipeline to ingest Excel from GCS and push to Bigquery. Used Wrangler to create the parse as Excel directive, where the data came back perfectly.  Issue is when deploying and running the pipeline, error collector captures the following -
`Error encountered while executing 'parse-as-excel' : Error encountered while executing 'parse-as-excel' : Column 'body' should be of type 'byte array' or 'ByteBuffer'`

Incoming data type(GCS Source) when marked as blob and byte fails in wrangler.
I am certain something basic is amiss, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, the incoming data body had to be set to byte(from source GCS).
For some reason this was selected as string, causing issues when deployment of the pipeline was effected.